# MySQL: Get bytes size from hex

Tags: mysql

Raywenderlich gave an example of a push token:

```
'740f4707 bebcf74f 9b7c25d4 8e335894 5f6aa01d a5ddb387 
462c7eaf 61bb78ad'
```

If I correct, push token are of bytes size 32.

I would like to get the byte size from it.

Here is MySQL statement:

```
SELECT LENGTH(CONV('740f4707 bebcf74f 9b7c25d4 8e335894 5f6aa01d a5ddb387 
462c7eaf 61bb78ad', 16, 2));
```

When I input this, it gives me a size of 31. I was expecting 32. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

CONV() converts a number to a *string* representation of that number.  Leading zeros are removed, so LENGTH() counts only the symbols in the string.
You could prepend your number with any number which you know will have the high bit set, and deduct the bit length of the extra values from the result.
i.e.

SELECT LENGTH(CONV('FF740f4707 bebcf74f 9b7c25d4 8e335894 5f6aa01d a5ddb387                                                                    462c7eaf 61bb78ad', 16, 2))-8;

gives you the 32 bits you expect.